# Search non project files(classes, methods) with Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

In IntelliJ IDEA you have a: "Search everywhere" option. You can search non project classes, methods and etc. Does visual studio has something like this? Because i can't seem to find it.

Comment: Edit > Find and Replace > Find in Files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the short answer is no. I use an extension called [FastFind](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PureDevSoftware.FastFind) and I believe Resharper also has something like this built in.